# Filter highest numbers out of an object

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following object, with points per sport for an individual person. This information comes out of a database, based on the search for "Jack Miller"

```
Jdata = {
    "name": "Jack Miller",
    "sports": {
        "Basketball": 2,
        "Football": 3,
        "Iceskating": 5,
        "Running": 4,
    }
}
```

I would like to display the top 2(3) sports for the name on my HTML page. Do to that, I was thinking to extract the information into an array like this:

```
SportVal = [];
SportNames = [];

for(var key in this.Jdata.sports){
    if(!this.Jdata.sports.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        continue;
    }
    this.SportVal.push(this.Jdata.scores[key]);
    this.SportNames.push(key)
}
```

Then I would have to sort the SportVal array in descending order and can use e.g. ngFor in the HTML to display the results.

However, how would I get back the corresponding Names? Also I don't think this is the most effective way, since I run into a problem if scores are equal. So do you maybe have a better idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do people almost always try to do this on front end when the logic is clearly on the backend...

Comment: @Ionut I was _just about_ to add that but didn't want to seem trite. One very good reason: it could be a public API whose logic you don't control.

Comment: @msanford, that should always be the only reason.

Comment: @Ionut I usually agree (and luckily work in a team with this UI/BE agreement). But I can think of various un-ideal project team compositions that might make this approach prohibitive (loads of UI devs and one overworked BE who only has time to maintain a few generic APIs). That in itself is the problem to solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Array.prototype.sort()` to do it.

```js
Jdata = {
"name": "Jack Miller",
"sports": {
    "Basketball": 2,
    "Football": 3,
    "Iceskating": 5,
    "Running": 4,
}
}

const sorted = Object.entries(Jdata.sports)
      .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
      .slice(0, 3)
      .map((pair) => pair[0]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: you could then use `slice(x)` to get the top 2 or 3 as asked by the OP :)

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara Good catch, missed that requirement :)